# Append Form And Elements jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, mobile, checkbox

Hello I want to append a form and checkbox elements, but the form is losing its style. The checkboxes should be combined in "list" and the button Save Attendance should be styled according to jquery Mobile.

How can I fix this please?

This is how it looks:

[image]

Code:

```
$('#editattendancecontent').append('<p>Who Attended?</p><form id="editattendanceform"><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="editattendancelist"></fieldset></div><input type="submit" value="Save Attendance" data-inline="true" /></form>');

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
{
    $('#editattendancelist').append('<input type="checkbox" id=\"' + json[i].userID + '\" class="custom" /><label for=\"' + json[i].userID + '\">'+json[i].name+'</label>').trigger('create');

}
$('input: checkbox').checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: screenshot is not appearing !

Comment: For buttons `$('#button_selector').button();` and checkboxes `$('[type=checkbox]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Two things :

1. You need to remove the `trigger("create")` call, which you are doing every time you loop through your data, which is plain wrong. This function is supposed to be called on the parent of the dynamic content.
2. Since you've got multiple items which need enhancement, buttons, checkboxes, etc, its better to use `trigger("create")` than enhance components one by one.

And I hope you are using `pageinit` if you are doing this on load of your page.

#### Code

After all these changes,

**Markup :**

```
<div data-role="page" id="mypage">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
         <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="editattendancecontent"></div>
<div>
```

**JS**

```
//pageinit method of the page
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage", function () {
    var json = [
        {
        userID: Math.random(),
        name: "Roger"
        }, 
        {
        userID: Math.random(),
        name: "Summer"
        }, 
        {
        userID: Math.random(),
        name: "William"
        }, 
        {
        userID: Math.random(),
        name: "Sunny"
        }, 
        {
        userID: Math.random(),
        name: "Walter"
        }
    ];

    console.log(json);

    $('#editattendancecontent').append('<p>Who Attended?</p><form id="editattendanceform"><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="editattendancelist"></fieldset></div><input type="submit" value="Save Attendance" data-inline="true" /></form>');

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        $('#editattendancelist').append('<input type="checkbox" id="' + json[i].userID + '" class="custom" /><label for="' + json[i].userID + '">' + json[i].name + '</label>') //removed trigger("create");

    }
    $(this).trigger("create"); //where $(this) is the page - you can also call it on $("#editattendancecontent"). That'll also work
});
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/HMQf7/1/

Comment: however, pageinit, only works one time when the page is loaded, if i come back to the page, it wont re-load

Comment: you need `pageshow` event.change `pageinit` to `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`, which will happen everytime you come back

Comment: ok thank you very much, i would give you +1000 if i could lol